# How to write a nawk script that prints out all except the blank lines and displays the total number of blank lines?

Tags: scripting

I have tried a couple different things but I cannot get it to work.
Mainly I'd just like to know how to exclude the blank lines.

command tried : `nawk '{print $0}' filename | grep -v " "`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
nawk -v count=0 '!NF {count++; next}; 1; END {print count}'
```

For all lines without any fields (`!NF`) (empty lines, in this case), increment the `count` and move on. If not, print the line (the default action for any true value, including `1`). At the end of input, print the `count`. We initialize `count` with `0` so that if every line is non-empty, `count` still has a value.

We could use `/^$/` instead of `!NF` - the latter might fail on lines containing only whitespace.